# Adding color and lines in a preloaded table (text file)

Tags: tables, color, verbatim, columns, report

I apologize in advance if this has already been asked. I've tried numerous combinations but to no avail. I have a text file with ~60 rows and 3 columns. The first thing I did (successfully) was to separate it into two columns. Next, I want to add horizontal and vertical lines between each row/column and color every other row (I know how to do this with manually made tables but this seems beyond my current capabilities).

The used packages (some of them may be redundant as I've tried pretty much everything) are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepacage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{green!70!yellow!40}{green!80!yellow!50}

\begin{minipage}\textwidth
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ |m{14cm}|m{14cm}|m{14cm}| }
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \VerbatimInput{textadin.txt}
  \end{multicols}
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{table}{Charge dependence}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: This is the result I get with the code I've given you.]

As per suggestions in the comments, here is a small part of the text file:

1        895    2.30329E-07

2    892     2.43065E-07

3    925     2.46525E-07

4    934     2.56787E-07

5    938     2.68926E-07

6    963     2.75502E-07

7    997     2.7988E-07

8    1021   2.87446E-07

9    1003   3.07749E-07

10  1021    3.17971E-07

11  1042    3.27689E-07

12  1102    3.25885E-07

13  1092    3.45891E-07

14  1093    3.6346E-07

15  1099    3.80185E-07

16  1129    3.89238E-07

17  1150    4.01908E-07

18  1186    4.09879E-07

19  1209    4.22892E-07

20  1239    4.34011E-07

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! You can indent your code with four spaces (or click the {}-icon), to make it look nice! I've suggested an edit for you in this regard. Furthermore, you should also make sure your code is runnable and verifiable. First add a `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. You should also consider including a (small version) of your text-file. You should also attempt to make your example more minimal, as you mention, take away the not-needed packages :)

Comment: Thank you both! I don't know how to add my text file except manually, is that what you meant @AndreasStorvikStrauman? 

@DavidCarlisle, I can't say that I understand your question. If I remove that part, the code refuses to compile.

Comment: Yes, @Kandrax, it's what I meant. Add it, but make sure to append four spaces before each line so that it shows up nicely :)

Comment: Is that okay? I can't seem to modify their horizontal distance :/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just tried it but that removes the color and the vertical borders.

Comment: You're right, I apologize, I didn't type one line of code here. It's been edited now. 

I declared three columns because I thought they would make sure that each multicolumn of three columns fall into place and not run out of the page.

Comment: no the entire multicolumn is in a single cell of the table.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what to make of that and I definitely don't know how that helps me achieve my goal.

Comment: Just add 4 spaces in front of every line of the text-file to make it look nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\VerbatimInput`-command is defined in the `fancyvrb`-package. However, it does not make an actual LaTeX-table, but includes the text "as is" or "verbatim". Instead, I'd use comma separated values (`.csv`). This means in your text-file: replace all spaces with commas, like in the code below
(I also added headers, which will be overwritten in the code below)

```
idx,num,rat
1,895,2.30329E-07
2,892,2.43065E-07
3,925,2.46525E-07
4,934,2.56787E-07
5,938,2.68926E-07
6,963,2.75502E-07
7,997,2.7988E-07
8,1021,2.87446E-07
9,1003,3.07749E-07
10,1021,3.17971E-07
11,1042,3.27689E-07
12,1102,3.25885E-07
13,1092,3.45891E-07
14,1093,3.6346E-07
15,1099,3.80185E-07
16,1129,3.89238E-07
17,1150,4.01908E-07
18,1186,4.09879E-07
19,1209,4.22892E-07
20,1239,4.34011E-07
```

Now I'd use the `\csvreader` command from the [`csvsimple`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) package to get it to be an actual table, and then the `\csvifoddrow` to change the colors, like this (a modified example from the [csvsimple docs](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \csvreader[head to column names,tabular=|l|l|l|,
    % Set header names
    table head=\hline\rowcolor{red!50!black}\color{white}\#%First is the hash-sign (#)
    & \color{white}Number%
    & \color{white}Ratio,%
    late after head=\\\hline\rowcolor{yellow!50},%What to do after header line
    late after line=\csvifoddrow{\\\rowcolor{yellow!50}}{\\\rowcolor{red!25}}\hline]%After every line, check if odd line, and if not
    {textadin.txt}{}{\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii}%Print col 1,2 and 3
\end{document}
```

Hope it helps :)

**Edit**: Added horizontal lines.

Comment: This works like a charm for coloring every other row, thanks! :)

How do I modify it so it does both this and separates the original table into two multicolumns?

Comment: Use the `multicol` package and just wrap the `\csvreader` inside`\begin{multicols}{2}` and \end{multicols}`, as you did in your question. Also: remember to upvote and/or accept an answer if it is satisfactory to you :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to create multicolumns, just extends it out of the paper :|

Comment: @Kandrax You could check the csvsimple docs or google. If no luck, I think it’s appropriate with a new question.